# Calculating the type of `pure (.)`

Tags: haskell

Source: Hutton, Graham. "*Programming in Haskell*" (p. 210)

> In addition to providing the functions `pure` and `<*>`, applicative functors are also required to satisfy four equational laws:

---

> 3. `x <*> (y <*> z) = (pure (.) <*> x <*> y) <*> z`

I calculated this type `pure (.) :: f ((b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c))`

However, that doesn't seem correct. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Looks right to me. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Thank you, @amalloy. I found online the correct type is `pure (.) :: f (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. That's why I am wondering how did they conclude that.

Comment: Well, _that_ one is clearly wrong. You can't possibly obtain a pure `c` in the end, short of extracting from the `f (b -> c)`, which is not possible in general (consider e.g. empty list).

Comment: Thank you, @leftaroundabout. Could you please clarify your comment ? Why do you mention the empty list and what that has to do with "pure c" ?

Comment: `[]` is an applicative functor, so one special case would be `[b->c] -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. What would `pure (.) [] f` return, since it has no functions of type `b -> c` that it could compose with the given `f :: a -> b` to produce a function of type `a -> c`?

Comment: If you just type `:t pure (.)` into GHCi, you get the correct type `f ((b->c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, @chepner ! Really clear !